# Is there a way to enable fts5 using an sqlite statement

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I was working on SQLite for android and came across fts5 for full-text search. I was interested in trying it out and I did but I got this error

> no such module: FTS5

I started searching what it meant and found out the I have to **enable** it or something

I was using **flutter and sqflite** for the project, is there a way to enable it using an **SQL statement**, or I have to do it **separately for Android and IOS**?

Comment: "is there a way to enable it using an SQL statement" -- not on Android. Your problem is that FTS5 is relatively new, so not all Android versions will support it (only API Level 24+ in general). Use FTS3 or FTS4 instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the comment, but how can I enable it, through an SQL statement or individually for Android and IOS? Actually, want to test all of the FTS(s)

Comment: "but how can I enable it" -- you would need to build your own version of Android from source, or package some independent copy of SQLite with your app that has SQLite 3.9.0 with FTS5 enabled. You cannot enable it via a SQL statement.

Comment: You can build it as a standalone extension module and load it. Assuming the Android version of sqlite was built with support for loading shared libraries...

Comment: @Jama Mohamed. I know this is late but did you find a solution for enabling FTS either through fts4 or fts5

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/702#issuecomment-969170268), sqflite is dependent on the sqlite version installed on the device. Unless fts5 is configured on the device by the manufacturer, sqflite will use the default (usually fts4).